# How check if a file exists in ansible windows?

Tags: ansible

I am using Ansible on windows and I have to check whether a file exists in **C:\Temp**.
 If the file Doesn't exist then I have to skip the task. I am trying to use the **win_stat** module and this is what I have which isn't working:

```
- name: Check that the ABC.txt exists
  win_stat:
    path: 'C:\ABC.txt '      

- name: Create DEF.txt file if ABC.txt exists
  win_file:
    path: 'C:\DEF.txt'
    state: touch
  when: stat_file.stat.exists == True
```

Comment: Please explain what does "*isn't working*" mean. Also remove quotes from the `path` argument.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So I didn't use the **win_stat** module correctly,

Should have added the register argument in my first 'task'.

This is how it works-

```
- name: Check that the ABC.txt exists
  win_stat: path= 'C:\ABC.txt'  
  register: stat_file

- name: Create DEF.txt file if ABC.txt exists 
  win_file:
    path: 'C:\DEF.txt'
    state: touch
  when: stat_file.stat.exists == True
```

Answer (score 6):

When I tried the answer above, it gave me a syntax error, instead I had to write it this way:

```
- name: Check that the ABC.txt exists
  win_stat: 
    path: 'C:\ABC.txt'  
  register: stat_file

- name: Create DEF.txt file if ABC.txt exists 
  win_file:
    path: 'C:\DEF.txt'
    state: touch
  when: stat_file.stat.exists == True
```

Comment: win_stat is so slow, I have 50 files to check and it takes about 2 mins and a half, I even disabled checksum calculation.. no improvement (get_checksum: False).  have you noticed any slowness ?

Comment: no, sorry, I haven't tried it on 50 files, nor do I know the cause.